# Is there a way to create separate environments on your computer with no way of detection?

Tags: privacy, operating-systems

I would like to know if there is a way to create two different systems/environments on your PC (Windows OS) that you will enter each by different username and password. When someone enters your computer he won't be able to detect there are 2 parallel systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends how much scrutiny you want to defend against. It would theoretically be possible to use full disk encryption with multiple partitions, decrypting each based on a distinct password. This falls apart if a user looks at the disk manager application in Windows though - they'd see partitions they couldn't use (but which they could reformat and take over the space of). It would also fail if they opened the computer, looked at the drive, and started wondering why they couldn't use all that space.

At a Windows level, there are various ways to determine whether there are other users, so you'd be able to see their presence, even if you can't access their data. These vary from names showing in quick access login screens, to being able to see the contents of the `c:\Users` folder or the security permissions screens.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew. Is there a way to revoke access to disk manager application and thus there won't be a way to see the disk space and partitions or alternatively to force the system to show different values?

Comment: You could write your own version of disk manager, which reports only on the parts of the system you want it to, but this would itself indicate that something was going on if the system is under forensic inspection - it wouldn't have the same filesize or contents as the legitimate application. You could certainly block the application using domain policies or similar though.

Comment: Thanks again, so practically there is not a technical way to hide information about disk space and the real disk usage and space would be detected.

Comment: It would probably work against casual inspection, just not against a determined investigator. As I said, depends what you want to protect against!

Comment: Thanks again. So If your computer got lost and only one system was properly encrypted. The one who got your computer might see the incompatibility in disk space and practically indicate that there is an additional system and there is no way to avoid it. Am I correct?

Comment: At the level you asked about, yes. If you're willing to boot, then run a second system, you can get around it - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption has some examples. If you've got further questions after reading that, probably best to open a new question though